# Dynamic web scraping by using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

when I use selenium to run this code the out shows an empty list. it is dynamic page change every 5 minute

```
url=r"C:\\Users\\PERSONL\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=url)
driver.get("https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/")
samples=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')
print(samples)
```

Comment: What information do you want to get?

Comment: I want to get game-result class

Comment: And what specific game do you want? Lucky 7?

Comment: you should use `time.sleep` or `wait_until`  or `implicitly_wait` to find elements  that load after certain time

Comment: Yes l want to ge lucky 7